# Question on Detailed Balance and Bayes' Rule

Tags: markov-chain-montecarlo, monte-carlo, markov-process, stationarity, metropolis-hastings

I think I am confused due to the lax notation typically used when dealing with probabilities and not having a formal probability background.

Bayes' Rule tells me that 
$$Pr(X_t=a|X_{t+1}=b)Pr(X_{t+1}=b) = Pr(X_{t+1}=b|X_t=a)Pr(X_t=a)$$

Detailed balance is that for a transition matrix P there exists a stationary distribution such that:
$$Pr(X_t=a|X_{t+1}=b)Pr(X_{t+1}=b) = Pr(X_{t+1}=b|X_t=a)Pr(X_t=a)$$ where the marginals correspond to the stationary distribution.

I am getting confused by the similarities between both of these. Am I conflating two completely different issues?

Edit: I am basing the definition of detailed balance on the one given on the wikipedia page for detailed balance. It states that let $\pi(s)$ be a density and $P(s',s)$ be a transition density from state $s'$ to $s$, then detailed balance is given by
$$\pi(s')P(s',s) = \pi(s) P(s,s')$$
Bayes rule that I originally gave is based on probabilities but also holds for densities.

Comment: How did you get that equation for detailed balance?

Comment: @JuhoKokkala The wikipedia page on detailed balance states that define P(s',s) to be transition probability density from state s' to state s and $\pi(s)$ as a probability density then detailed balance is $\pi(s') P(s',s) = \pi(s) P(s,s')$. This is in densities but bayes theorem also holds for densities.

Comment: Could you edit that information into the question? Something like "Wikipedia article states (equation),  because (explanation) I interpret this to mean (equation currently in question)".

Comment: @JuhoKokkala done.

Comment: This is missing the "because" part - how does $\pi(s')\,P(s',s) = \pi(s)\,P(s,s')$ imply your equation?  Am I guessing correctly: you think that when $a=s, b=s'$, $P(s,s')=P(X_t = a \mid X_{t+1}=b)$?

Comment: It's not Bayes rule, it's [conditional probability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_probability) $P(A \cap B) = P(A|B)P(B)$.

Comment: @JuhoKokkala $a=s, b=s', P(s,s') = P(X_{t+1} = b | X_t = a)$. Note $P(s,s')$ is going from state $s$ to $s'$.

Comment: @Tim I am using the statement of Bayes' Theorem on wikipedia page and just taking the denominator to the other side. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayes%27_theorem

Comment: @user52932 sorry I mixed up $s$ and $s'$,   I was after the $P(X_t = a \mid X_{t+1} = b)$ factor that appears on the left hand side of your previous eq, where do you get that? ($P(s', s)?$)?  (I think this is a good question if this part is clarified, and an interesting answer can be written.  I'll try to get back to this later if no-one else answers)

Comment: @JuhoKokkala I am assuming you are asking about the detailed balance equation. The LHS is $Pr(X_t = a | X_{t+1}=b) Pr(X_{t+1}=b)$. This corresponds to $P(s',s) \pi(s')$ from the wiki definition. And the right hand side is similarly defined.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is indeed confusing when using confusing notations! As, e.g., in your question with $Pr(\cdot)$ for all probabilities.

Let us consider an MCMC algorithm where detailed balance holds. This means that, given the Markov transition kernel $K$ with density $k(x,x')$ [which is also the generator of the Markov chain in that $X_{t+1}|X_t=x\sim k(x,x')$], there exists a probability density $\pi$ such that$$\pi(x)k(x,x')=\pi(x')k(x',x)$$i.e., there is time reversibility in the Markov chain: if $X_t$ is distributed from $\pi$, $X_t\sim\pi$, then $X_{t+1}$ is distributed from $\pi$,*and also* $X_{t-1}$ is distributed from $\pi$.

**Why is this different from Bayes' rule?** It is true that Bayes' rule allows for the inversion of a joint distribution from *marginal of $X$ times conditional of $Y$* to *marginal of $X$ times conditional of $Y$*. However, if one starts with a random variable $X_t$ with marginal distribution (density) $\pi_t$ and applies the Markov kernel $K$, then $X_{t+1}$ will be distributed from a marginal distribution (density) $\pi_{t+1}$, providing the general equality
$$\pi_t(x)k(x,x')=\pi_{t+1}(x')\tilde{k}(x',x)$$
where $\tilde{k}$ denotes the density of the time-reverse kernel [obtained as the distribution of $X_t$ given $X_{t+1}$]. Therefore the detail balance property is very specific wrt Bayes' inversion formula in that

1. $\pi_t(x)=\pi_{t+1}(x)$ [stationarity]
2. $k(x,x')=\tilde{k}(x,x $ [reversibility]

and it only holds for a subfamilly of MCMC algorithms like the Metropolis-Hastings algorithm.